# How to vectorize pandas code where it depends on previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to vectorize a code snippet in pandas:

I have a pandas dataframe generated like this:

|  | ids | ftest | vals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q52EG | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Q52EG | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Q52EG | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Q52EG | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Q52EG | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | QQ8Q4 | 0 | 5 |
| 6 | QQ8Q4 | 0 | 6 |
| 7 | QQ8Q4 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | QQ8Q4 | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | QVIPW | 1 | 9 |

If any id in `ids` column has a value 1 in the `ftest` column, then all the subsequent rows with same id should be marked as 1 in `has_hist` column and it doesnt depend on the current `ftest` value as shown in the dataframe below:

|  | ids | ftest | vals | has_hist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q52EG | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Q52EG | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Q52EG | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | Q52EG | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | Q52EG | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | QQ8Q4 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | QQ8Q4 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 7 | QQ8Q4 | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| 8 | QQ8Q4 | 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | QVIPW | 1 | 9 | 0 |

I am doing this using a iterative approach like this:

```
previous_present = {}
has_prv_history = []
for index, value in id_df.iterrows():
    my_id = value["ids"]
    ftest_mentioned = value["ftest"]
    previous_flag = 0
    if my_id in previous_present.keys():
        previous_flag = 1
    elif (ftest_mentioned == 1):
        previous_present[my_id] = 1
    has_prv_history.append(previous_flag)
id_df["has_hist"] = has_prv_history
```

Can this code be vectorized without using `apply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two key functions for this kind of tasks are `shift` and `ffill`, applied per group. For this specific question:

```py
df2["has_hist"] = df.groupby("ids").ftest.shift().where(lambda s: s.eq(1))
df2["has_hist"] = df2.groupby("ids").has_hist.ffill().fillna(0).astype("int32")
```

Here is a variant with `transform`, which however is often slower than "pure" Pandas operations in my experience:

```py
df2 = (
    df
    .groupby("ids")
    .ftest.transform(
        lambda s: (
            s
            .shift()
            .where(lambda t: t.eq(1))
            .ffill()
            .fillna(0)
            .astype("int32")
        )
    )
)
```